# Is there a way to have Yii CActiveForm to highlight input fields?

Tags: php, yii

When we use CactiveForm Widget like this:

```php
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
```

We get validation messages but, the input field himself our the *textfield*, don't get any class.

I wish to, when *Yii* validates, a class appears on the input field so that it could render highlighted.

`CHtml::activeTextField` actually does this:

```php
<?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'name') ?>
```

Any way to do this using *CActiveForm* ?

**Added:**

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'event-form',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions'=>
```

Comment: a class does appear, `error`. what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @bool.dev thanks a lot. Upon inline client side validation, I can't see any class on the input field called "error" when using  `echo $form->textField($model, 'name');` - could this be something else ? The only thing I get is a div with a class: "errorMessage" containing the error message.

Comment: inline client side validation as in ajaxvalidation? are you using clientOptions of CActiveForm?

Comment: @bool.dev - Yes. I'm using clientOptions.

Comment: @bool.dev: CActiveForm::$enableClientValidation not the same as CActiveForm::$enableAjaxValidation. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#enableClientValidation-detail

Comment: @fsb i was talking about clientOptions, like validateOnSubmit, and validateOnChange, you can read the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#clientOptions-detail) for clarity on those options. MEM there's nothing wrong with your code, i have use CActiveForm many times. there's only one last thing, do you have the css classes as they are in default. for example, is the textfield inside a div structure like in my answer?

Comment: @fsb however i agree that mem could be talking about either or both, but since he hasn't mentioned enableClientValidation, i'd assumed its only ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the default error class to be attached you need to have the structure of your form as it is in the default auto generated forms, something like this:

```
<div class="form">
  <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    ...
  )); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Edit: Meaning you need an `inputContainer` for each input field, because that's how the default css and default implementation of *jquery.activeform.js* is. To change this behavior we can simply add another css rule to the default *form.css* file, which by default adds errors only to **divs** inside `div.form`.

```
/*
 default css
*/
div.form div.error input,
div.form div.error textarea,
div.form div.error select,
div.form input.error,
div.form textarea.error,
div.form select.error
{
    background: #FEE;
    border-color: #C00;
}
```

So you can change that to your liking, but minimum required will be :

```
div.error input, div.error textarea, div.error select {/* styles */}
```

Incase the above doesn't work and you want to assign error class to *input elements* individually then you can use the `afterValidate` and `afterValidateAttribute` callbacks of [CActiveForm's `clientOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#clientOptions-detail), where you'll need to add the error css class to the input, and also have a css rule to match such inputs:

```
input.error, textarea.error, select.error {/*styles*/}
```

Incase you use some form of client validation, like you have done in beforeValidate, you'll need to [`addClass('error');`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to your inputs, with the above css in place.

Comment: i'm not sure if this could be the mistake in your code, but let me know, how this works out

Comment: I've tried that earlier with no success. I will return in some hours and try that again, letting you know. thks a lot

Comment: ok. If I put that extra useless div on the markup, I indeed get an error class on that DIV still, not on the input. With css we can deal with it. But, that extra garbage div it's really annoying. Isn't there another way to add a class on a element upon validation, without forcing us to dirty our html ?

Comment: yes, it is possible, which is the extra useless div according to you? form or row? fsb's comment has gotten me thinking, are you using enableClientValidation? if yes my answer might need further fine tuning, so let me know, soon. i might also have to look at your form's code.

Comment: the I was talking about it's the div you say we must have. That div with class="row"; By useless I mean, extra markup that I don't need for semantically of visual proposes. That div it's exactly that. Yii is forcing me to have it in order to all a class to it... :s - Is your second option: "afterValidate" an alternative ? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13108/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-mem)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a class to an element using the htmlOptions parameter, which allows you to pass attributes to the tag. e.g.:

```
<? php echo $form->textField($model, 'name', array('class'=>'textFieldClass')); ?>
```

Comment: I don't wish to have a class ALWAYS on the element. I wish to have it only when validation occurs.