# How can I customize yii form validation?

Tags: php, yii, validation

I am new to Yii. I'm doing some tasks with the help of yii wiki and documentations. Now I have completed a form for employee details updation with validation. But I dont know where this validation process is actually going on.Even though I can see the script for validation. And how can I customize the error messages? Can anyone help me to catch this??

Answer (score 2):

For built-in validators in general you can customize error messages by setting the [`message`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#message-detail) property of the validation when defining the rule within your model's `rules()`.

Some built-in validators have additional specific error messages that you can set, for example [`CNumberValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberValidator) also has the properties [`tooSmall`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberValidator#tooSmall-detail) and [`tooBig`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberValidator#tooBig-detail). For validators with additional error messages, these are mentioned prominently in the validator's reference documentation.

When using custom validation rules you specify the error message explicitly using [`CModel::addError`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#addError-detail) or [`CValidator::addError`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#addError-detail), so again you have full control over it.

When displaying input forms you can customize the CSS class of various elements by using the properties [`CHtml::errorCss`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorCss-detail) (CSS class for an input element that has an error), [`CHtml::errorMessageCss`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorMessageCss-detail) (class for the error message that displays next to the input element) and [`CHtml::errorSummaryCss`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorSummaryCss-detail) (class for the error summary that usually appears on top of the form if you choose to print it). Since Yii 1.1.13 you can also customize [`CHtml::errorContainerTag`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorContainerTag-detail) to select the tag name for each validation error message (this tag will get the `errorMessageCss` class).

Answer (score 1):

you haven't given us much to work with so here is an example checking a specific format of a phone number, this snippet is in a model, you'll have lots more rules in your model:

```
public function rules()
{
    array('contact_phone', 'phoneNumber'), //custom check fn see below
}

/** 
 * check the format of the phone number entered
 * @param string $attribute the name of the attribute to be validated
 * @param array $params options specified in the validation rule
 */
 public function phoneNumber($attribute,$params='')
 {
    if(preg_match("/^\(?\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/",$this->$attribute) === 0)
    {   
        $this->addError($attribute,
            'Contact phone number is required and  may contain only these characters: "0123456789()- " in a form like (858) 555-1212 or 8585551212 or (213)555 1212' );  
    }   
 }
```

You should also check the YII wiki for lots of good info about validation such as [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/)

Comment: Thanks sdjuan..!

But actually what I mean is, where I can find the code for changing the layout (style) of error messages and its content.

Comment: Your question asks "how can I customize the error messages" and that is the answer I have provided. Part of that answers how to change the content of the error message. Where its says "Contact phone number is required...' you can put whatever you like. If you want something else you should re-phrase your question. For CSS on errors try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212176/is-there-a-way-to-have-yii-cactiveform-to-highlight-input-fields

Comment: Also check this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#error-detail which gives detail on how to change the error CSS

Comment: Am sorry, if i fail to convey my requirements and thanks for Your clarification. Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

I might just put here one of my custom validators with customized errors.
See how i employ `$this->getAttributeLabel($field)` to get the attribute name/label for a given field inside the validator for outputting it into a custom error:

```
public function checkFormFields($params)
{
    $patternAccount = '/\d{20}/'; // двадцать цифр
    $patternBic = '/\d{9}/'; // девять цифр
    $patternINN = '/\d{10,12}/'; // от десяти до двенадцати цифр
    $fields = explode(',', $params); // get the names of required fields
    foreach ($fields as $field)
     { 
         if($this->$field == '') 
            $this->addError($this->$field, Yii::t('general', $this->getAttributeLabel($field) ) .' '. Yii::t('general', 'should not be empty')); 
        if( $field == 'CurrentAccount' OR $field == 'CorrespondentAccount' ) 
        { 
            if(!preg_match($patternAccount, $this->$field))
                $this->addError($this->$field, Yii::t('general', $this->getAttributeLabel($field) ) .' '. Yii::t('general', 'should contain exact 20 digits')); 
        }               
        elseif( $field == 'BIC' ) 
        { 
            if(!preg_match($patternBic, $this->$field))
                $this->addError($this->$field, Yii::t('general', $this->getAttributeLabel($field) ) .' '. Yii::t('general', 'should contain exact 9 digits')); 
        }
        elseif( $field == 'INN' ) 
        { 
            if(!preg_match($patternINN, $this->$field))
                $this->addError($this->$field, Yii::t('general', $this->getAttributeLabel($field) ) .' '. Yii::t('general', 'should contain between 10 and 12 digits')); 
        }
     }
```

Hope this will help you to get clear how to customize errors.